# Is there a PostGIS equivalent to ESRI Spatial Analyst COMBINE?

Tags: postgis, combine

The ESRI Spatial Analyst COMBINE tool accepts multiple raster inputs and outputs a new raster with a unique number corresponding to unique combinations of values from the inputs.  It also provides a translation VAT.

I want to do this open source.  Does PostGIS have a way to do this?  GRASS?  Other options?  I am building my geospatial app with MapWindow and VB.net to run as a desktop Windows app.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the [ST_MapAlgebra function](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html). It is somewhat non-tirival if you haven't used Postgis rasters before :-)

Comment: Or ST_Union() if your rasters are stacked.